# Network Manager error - "cannot send router solicitation"

Tags: networking, networkmanager

I see this error occuring for network manager, but only after the laptop goes to sleep mode, and I come back to wake it up.

```
NetworkManager[2040]: <error> [1456121915.287806] [rdisc/nm-lndp-rdisc.c:68] send_rs(): (enp7s0): cannot send router solicitation: -101.
NetworkManager[2040]: <error> [1456121919.285940] [rdisc/nm-lndp-rdisc.c:68] send_rs(): (enp7s0): cannot send router solicitation: -101.
NetworkManager[2040]: <error> [1456121923.285494] [rdisc/nm-lndp-rdisc.c:68] send_rs(): (enp7s0): cannot send router solicitation: -101.
NetworkManager[2040]: <error> [1456121927.286665] [rdisc/nm-lndp-rdisc.c:68] send_rs(): (enp7s0): cannot send router solicitation: -101.
NetworkManager[2040]: <error> [1456121931.287111] [rdisc/nm-lndp-rdisc.c:68] send_rs(): (enp7s0): cannot send router solicitation: -101.
NetworkManager[2040]: <error> [1456121935.286769] [rdisc/nm-lndp-rdisc.c:68] send_rs(): (enp7s0): cannot send router solicitation: -101.
NetworkManager[2040]: <error> [1456121939.287232] [rdisc/nm-lndp-rdisc.c:68] send_rs(): (enp7s0): cannot send router solicitation: -101.
NetworkManager[2040]: <error> [1456121943.287549] [rdisc/nm-lndp-rdisc.c:68] send_rs(): (enp7s0): cannot send router solicitation: -101.
NetworkManager[2040]: <error> [1456121947.287043] [rdisc/nm-lndp-rdisc.c:68] send_rs(): (enp7s0): cannot send router solicitation: -101.
NetworkManager[2040]: <error> [1456121951.289311] [rdisc/nm-lndp-rdisc.c:68] send_rs(): (enp7s0): cannot send router solicitation: -101.
```

I am able to fix this using `sudo systemctl restart network-manager`, and the error stops printing.

Also this particular error prevents me from sshing into the laptop from another computer, once I restarted the `network-manager`, everything started to work again.

Is there anyway to make it so that I don't have to restart network-manager?

I'm using just plain iptables FYI. I'm also connected to both the WiFi and ethernet at the same time. And in this building's network, when connecting to both ethernet and wifi, the I am not able to send outgoing packets using the wifi interface, but I can SSH into the wifi interface. Would this have something to do with the error?

Answer (score 2):

If you have IPv6 disabled in `sysctl.conf`, check the interface configuration (`/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp7s0`) and set `IPV6INIT=no`.
Then you can restart the network service or reboot the system and check for errors again.

Comment: Why would IPV6 be affecting this?

Comment: In IPv4, typically router information is configured either statically or by DHCP; in IPv6, router solicitations and advertisements are used for stateless autoconfiguration - even without DHCPv6 at all. In short, "router solicitation" is usually an IPv6 thing.

Comment: I don't disable my IPv6 however.